# Cannot import gdal_array

Tags: python, gdal

I attempted to use GDAL without installing due to not having rights to install on this computer. I managed to get several gdal modules working, but when I attempted to use ReadAsArray() I received the import error

```
ImportError: No module named _gdal_array
```

I looked through the python folder and found that gdal and gdalconst both had pyd files and compiled files, but gdal_array does not.

When I ran VersionInfo() I got the value 1910 for gdal if that helps. I also have python 2.6 and numpy

Does anyone know a way I could fix this problem without using a gdal installer?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @ustroetz Yes, Windows 7

Comment: I have the same issue. Using the GDAL 64 bit version, the _gdal_array.pyd is NOT generated and when I call ReadAsArray() is returning the error: ImportError: No module named _gdal_array.
Using the GDAL 32 bit version the _gdal_array.pyd file is generated and it is working.
How can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: @Federico As I recall, I followed Lafleur's instructions that he posted in my other question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82977/is-it-possible-to-use-gdal-without-admin-rights/83297#83297) and it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poking around I figured out that a bunch of gdal bundles are missing files, including the maptools.org ones.  http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-May/028708.html

I found a gdal 1.10 version that is working for me.  Put the install instructions with the original question: 
[Is it possible to use GDAL without admin rights?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82977/is-it-possible-to-use-gdal-without-admin-rights/83297#83297)

Answer (score 5):

This happens when `numpy` was not yet installed during the installation of `gdal-python`.  This normally only affects folks who install using `pip` and install gdal before numpy. `numpy` is an optional build requirement and the package will install but quietly not include the `_gdal_array` component

To resolve, force a reinstall (rebuild of the package), via pip:

1. `pip install numpy`
2. `pip install --force-reinstall gdal`

or can be done using system package manager.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - correct explanation of the reason together with a solution that works. Thank you!

Comment: No such luck for me :/

Comment: @Shayne what does the log say when it builds the _gdal_array module?

Answer (score -2):

In case you need gdal+python on windows x64, you should compile it manually.